# How to serve static files in vanilla nodeJS

Tags: html, node.js

To preface this, I am currently learning how to use vanilla nodeJS to host html files for a personal project. I am using the following code to do this. I realize that in order to display images with html I need to publicly serve the files; however, I am not sure how to do this with the provided code below.  I appreciate any feedback and contributions on how to achieve this.

```js
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
   switch (path) {
      case "/homepage.html":
         fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
               response.writeHead(404);
               response.write(error);
               response.end();
            } else {
               response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
               response.write(data);
               response.end();
            }
         });
         break;
      case "/page1.html":
         fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
               response.writeHead(404);
               response.write(error);
               response.end();
            } else {
               response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
               response.write(data);
               response.end();
            }
         });
         break;
      default:
         response.writeHead(404);
         response.write("Oops this doesn't exist!");
         response.end();
   }
});
server.listen(8008);

console.log("Server is running on port 8008");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Popper JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class = "row">
         <div class = "col-sm-4">
            <img src = "/image.jpg/" class = "img-fluid" class = "rounded-circle">
         </div>
         <div class = "col-sm-8">

         </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hei, try this piece of code:

```js
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
   switch (path) {
      case "/homepage.html":
         fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
               response.writeHead(404);
               response.write(error);
               response.end();
            } else {
               response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
               response.write(data);
               response.end();
            }
         });
         break;
      case "/page1.html":
         fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
               response.writeHead(404);
               response.write(error);
               response.end();
            } else {
               response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
               response.write(data);
               response.end();
            }
         });
         break;
      default:
        //  response.writeHead(404);
        //  response.write("Oops this doesn't exist!");
        //  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        //  response.write(data);
         console.log('I am here for path ', path);
         fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
               response.writeHead(404);
               response.write(error);
               response.end();
            } else {
               response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'image/jpg'});
               response.write(data);
               response.end();
            }
         });
   }
});
server.listen(8008);

console.log("Server is running on port 8008");
```

So, because for the image you did not have a case in your switch the default was used.
I specified in the default case what to do.
As you can see if you end up with 100 static files you have to specify a case for each and every file. 
Note that the example above will work only for jpg images .
This will be very hard to maintain and not recomended because it will (possibly) mix your statics with the website's logic.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use express module, it already has this functionality and it is very, very easy to use.

```
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/mystaticcontent'));
app.use('/hiddenfolder', express.static(__dirname+'/mystaticcontent/'));
app.listen(8008);
```

For the first `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/mystaticcontent'));` if you put image.jpg in this folder, you can access it using this url: http://localhost:8008/image.jpg

Here `app.use('/hiddenfolder', express.static(__dirname+'/mystaticcontent/'));` you hide the real name of the folder , the image is accessible at `http://localhost:8008/hiddenfolder/image.jpg`

If you don't want to use express, maybe you should have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static get inspired about how to write your own statics module.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

*** I have found an easier way to serve static files using `node-static` library
provided in `nodejs` docs ***

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');

var file = new(static.Server)(__dirname);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8080);
```

A link to the same is here [NODE JS Docs](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/)